# gcloud - no permissions for any API even though I am owner and works fine through web UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am the owner of my newly created organization, I created a project under this organization and linked it to the organization billing account where I have 1000$ in credits. Through the web UI, I am able to spin up clusters, VMs, networks... But when I want to do so through gcloud, I am getting permissions denied. E.g.:

```
$ gcloud compute networks list
API [compute.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [XXX]. 
Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)? 
(y/N)?  y

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.networks.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

but I can see in the web UI GCP that the API is clearly enabled (and can be used), it's just the gcloud not letting me work with them. The account under gcloud is exactly the same I am using in the web console - validated by `gcloud auth list` and:

```
$ gcloud config configurations describe myproject
is_active: true
name: myproject
properties:
  compute:
    region: europe-west1
    zone: europe-west1-b
  core:
    account: <my-email>
    project: <the-project-I-want>
```

or

```
$ gcloud services list
ERROR: (gcloud.services.list) User [<myusername>] does not have permission to access project [myproject] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
```

It works totally fine with a different account (and different organization/projects), but I didn't set up that one in the past. What should I do? Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**
After `gcloud init`, at least the `gcloud services list` started to work. But the rest did not:

```
$ gcloud services list
NAME                              TITLE
bigquery-json.googleapis.com      BigQuery API
cloudapis.googleapis.com          Google Cloud APIs
clouddebugger.googleapis.com      Stackdriver Debugger API
cloudtrace.googleapis.com         Stackdriver Trace API
compute.googleapis.com            Compute Engine API
container.googleapis.com          Kubernetes Engine API
containerregistry.googleapis.com  Container Registry API
datastore.googleapis.com          Cloud Datastore API
logging.googleapis.com            Stackdriver Logging API
monitoring.googleapis.com         Stackdriver Monitoring API
oslogin.googleapis.com            Cloud OS Login API
pubsub.googleapis.com             Cloud Pub/Sub API
servicemanagement.googleapis.com  Service Management API
serviceusage.googleapis.com       Service Usage API
sql-component.googleapis.com      Cloud SQL
storage-api.googleapis.com        Google Cloud Storage JSON API
storage-component.googleapis.com  Google Cloud Storage
$ gcloud compute networks create testing-net --subnet-mode=custom '--description=Network to host testing kubernetes cluster'

API [compute.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [{PROJECT_ID}]. 
Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)? 
(y/N)?  y

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.networks.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

^ the `PROJECT_ID` above shows my organization's ID, not the actual project under this org.

Comment: Execute `gcloud auth list`. Verify that the active account (has an asterisk) is the account that you have given yourself OWNER permission. You can also execute `gcloud auth login` to specify the credentials that you want to use. Use the same ones that you login to the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: I realize that you mentioned `gcloud auth list` in your question, but you are clearly overlooking something setup with `gcloud` and your credentials.

Comment: Yes, the asterisk marking `ACTIVE` in `gcloud auth list` is on the exactly same email address as the one I see in GCP IAM, where is this (only) account marked as `Owner`. Btw. `gcloud projects list` returns appropriate projects for this organization, so some communication must go through fine, it's the API not working.

Comment: Run `gcloud auth login` using the same credentials that you login to the Google Cloud Console. The credentials that you think you are using is not what `gcloud` is actually using - provided that your permissions are actually correct on your credentials. You may just want to run `gcloud init` to reset everything and recreate your authorization.

Comment: So, unfortunately, it didn't work entirely. `gcloud init` again made `gcloud services list` work, but not e.g. creating network. But I noticed that this is may be suspicious: `API [compute.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [{PROJECT_ID}]. ` - that project ID doesn't correspond to the actual project, but to the organization. Even though I did `gcloud config set project <project_id>`, it's still probably trying to work on the organization? I updated my question.

Comment: OK, that was it! I specified wrong project id and it defaulted to the org

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the problem was that I used the wrong `project_id` when `gcloud config set project` and gcloud defaulted to organization for some reason.

So I had to find correct project id using `gcloud projects list` and then use `gcloud config set project {PROJECT-ID}` (**not** the project name!)

Comment: Excellent - I am glad that you solved this. Your Q&A should help others.

Answer (score 0):

**gcloud init** - if you wanted to switch gcloud to work between projects which will configure its settings to point to the right project.